# How do I use a Solidity Library in NodeJs

Tags: web3js, javascript, ethers.js

Can I interact with the Solidity library in nodejs with the ethers library if I have the "my_specific_library.json" file generated by truffle in the compilation of the the my_specific_library.sol file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use ethers.js in your Node.js environment to deploy or interact with your contract on the ethereum network. You can find the relevant documentation [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract--creating).

As an example:

```js
const jsonFile = require('./path/to/my_specific_library.json');

// deploying
const myContractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(jsonFile.abi, jsonFile.evm.bytecode, signer);
const myContract = await myContractFactory.deploy(); // also pass if any constructor args here

// creating contract instance if already deployed contract previously
const addressOfDeployedContract = '0x123..';
const myContract = new ethers.Contract(addressOfDeployedContract, jsonFile.abi, signer);
```